# What's the format of this Date

Tags: java, json, jackson

A web api that I use return this in the Json response :

```
"timestamp": "2014-12-30T15:54:19Z",
```

I use Jackson to map the response to object. I have this in my class

```
@JsonProperty("notificationtimestamp")
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="", timezone="") //I don't know what to put here
```

My question what should I put in the JsonFromat annotation for pattern and timezone?

I'm thinking to put:

```
yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ
```

Comment: have a look at this link : http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [docs](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) said:

> ... pattern may contain SimpleDateFormat-compatible pattern
>   definition.

Than the pattern should be

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'
```

note the quotes.